# Rails advanced Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want to do an advanced Active Record query on my models through a join and count all the records. I don't know whether it's possible to do what I want but I think it can be done.

I want know how many times a single song is played on a radio station. I tried the following but it obviously didn't work.

```
@top_songs = Song.joins(:radiostation).where("radiostations.id = ?", 1).order(total_counter: :desc)
```

I played around with group as well though the Generalplaylist model but the downside is that it gives a hash as a result and not an ActiveRecord Relation.

```
Generalplaylist.where("radiostation_id = ?", 1).group(:song_id).count
```

Is there another way to get the result?

Here's my model for my radio playlists website

```
generalplaylist.rb

class Generalplaylist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
  belongs_to :radiostation
  belongs_to :artist
end

song.rb

class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :generalplaylists
  has_many :radiostations, through: :generalplaylists
  belongs_to :artist
end

radiostaion.rb

class Radiostation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :generalplaylists
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :generalplaylists
  has_many :songs
  has_many :radiostations, through: :generalplaylists
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ActiveRecord relation doesn't really apply after you've grouped and counted.

The group and count will give you aggregate results, whereas an ActiveRecord relation is really designed for when you need row level access to individual records.

So in this case, a hash is the result you want.

Comment: Hi Joshua, I've ended up using the group methode and processed the group to find the Song details that I was looking for. It seemed the best for my situation. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an ActiveRecord Relation (although Joshua points out you don't really need one) you can use Generalplaylist for that.  Assuming you want to count a specfic song `my_song` at a specific radiostation `my_radiostation` you can do...

```
Generalplaylist.where(song: my_song, radiostation: my_radiostation).count
```

Comment: Thanks Steve for your anwser. I ended up using the group methode since that was must suitable for my situation.

Comment: No problem, glad you got a solution!